# How to write a grunt-shell task which works cross-platform?

Tags: node.js, shell, gruntjs

I'm trying to write a grunt task which removes a directory and its contents.

Here is config file

```
{
  "name": "lorem",
  "homepage": "ipsum",
  "version": "0.9.5",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-shell": "~0.5.0",
  }
}
```

and grunt.js file

```
// Whole Gruntfile.js so far
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        shell: {
            clean: {
                command: 'rm dist -r',
                options: { stdout: true, failOnError: true }
            }
         }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell:clean']);
};
```

This probably work on `linux`, but what if the machine is `windows` or `osx`?
Is there any cross-platform solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell commands uses the system shell, which differs between OSes. If you want something cross-platform, just do it in JS. As for your use-case you could use [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean), [trash](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash), or [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf).

Comment: Thanks for explanation Sindre. That will work. It would be better solution to use node for more complicated tasks.